# Send notification from SES to the RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I need to get email(s) from SES in my module (not in AWS, some Java project). My module is connected to RabbitMQ.
By my plan, I want to send a notification from SES via SNS to RabbitMQ where my module can subscribe it and make a request to SES API. Is it possible?

Is it a suitable link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html?

Comment: So you want something to email a certain address, SES to process it, forward to SNS, have SNS trigger RabbitMQ and then your module can process it from RabitMQ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's my goal.